=vlookup using two Excel files
vlookup in Excel
=VLOOKUP(A3,[Q_Joining_Demograph_Network_08.14.24.xlsx]Sheet2!$A:$A,2)
is throwing a #REF! error in the cell.
tried using data>text to columns thinking the to columns are not the same data type. This is not working.

Are you trying to do vlookup across two excel workbooks?

yes two excel workbooks

Is the second workbook open, and have you double checked that you got its name right in your reference?

Actually this part looks weird as an Excel referenced $A:$A,2. I’m not an Excel expert so I may be wrong but I’d make sure it’s a valid reference on its own first within that workbook before trying the cross workbook vlookup.

I figured it out. You were correct I need to reference all the columns. $A:$F,2    Thank you.
